# XSS Attack and HtmlEncode

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using C# and VS 2010.
In an effort to do some final testing, I found that some areas need protecting.
Using a simple script to test:

```
    <script>alert('123');</script>
```

Of course the page breaks with the popup message:

```
 JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 
 An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. 
 The status code returned from the server was: 500
```

In the page directive, it is set

```
 ValidateRequest="false"
```

And also using AntiXSSLibrary with a textbox set to encode:

```
   string test = Encoder.HtmlEncode(txtSomeTextBox.Text);
```

The above error occurs on a page with an updatepanel.
And testing on a page without an updatepanel, the error is:

```
 A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTest="<script>alert('123')...").
```

EXACT same code on that page as well.
The information being input is stored in SQL Server and later viewed by a coworker.
Why is the page breaking?
Why is the HtmlEncode not working as expected?
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link!
I have searched everywhere for hours and with no luck.
Especially here.
And now I see it takes a simple adjustment to the web.config file.

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Thanks!!!!!